# Format int num in money javascript

Tags: javascript

I've already searched but I haven't found a solution. I have a list products and each product has a different price:

ex1: 53990
ex2: 160115

How can I change these to a currency format? I'm from Brazil so ex1 needs to be: `R$ 539,00` and ex2: `R$ 1.601,15`

I've already tried the code below, but it hasn't worked:

```html
row.price.toFixed(3).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,')
```

Comment: Please use the snippet to create a [mcve] - your description does not make sense and there are thousands of examples how to format money including Indian Lahk etc

Answer (score -3, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the [accounting](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/) library:

```
var accounting = require('accounting')
accounting.formatMoney(12345.67, {
  symbol: 'R$',
  decimal: ',',
  thousand: '.',
  format: '%s %v',
})
```